# C : In function, malloc two dimensional array and duplicatating array of argument does not work

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** asd(int map[][7]);

int main(void)
{
    int **child_map = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 6);
    int i, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        child_map[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 7);


    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            child_map[i][k] = 10;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            printf("%3d", child_map[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int **map = NULL;
    map = asd(child_map);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            printf("%3d", map[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int** asd(int map[][7])
{
    int **a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 6);
    int i, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 7);


    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            a[i][k] = map[i][k];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

In function, a[i][k] and map[i][k] are not mapped. Value of array a is very strange like 99882978. Why doesn't it work?
I have been made tree of game like go and each tree node has copy of parent's map. So i made function malloc two dimesional array , copies map of parent and return pointer of copy map. But it do not work... 
I'm very stuck here...

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: what do you mean? i don't understand

Comment: You should write `int **child_map = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 6);` without `(int **)` before `malloc`. Click on the link to learn why.

Comment: oh i checked it. i will trynit now.

Comment: `int **` is no 2D array, nor can it point to one. If you need a 2D array, **use one**!

Comment: "Does not work" is not a **specific** problem statement as required by site-rules. Read [ask], provide a [mcve] and all required information.

Comment: @Olaf i made it ! thanks !

Comment: And why don't you `malloc` a 2D array and just `memcpy` it? That`s just two function calls. Why simple if we can do it complicated? As a sidenote: don't use magic numbers! Pass teh lengths of each dimension as arguments or use constant-like macros.

Answer (score 2):

`child_map` is an array of pointers. The declaration `int map[][7]` is for a 2-dimensional array of `int`, not an array of pointers. You need to change `asd` to:

```
int **asd(int **map)
```

Comment: This is surprisingly difficult to spot...

Comment: OP wants a 2D array, so why not allocate and return one?

Comment: @Olaf Dynamically allocating a 2D array is tricky. You can do it with `malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int))`, but you can't access this with `array[i][j]`, you need to do the conversion from 2D to linear addressing yourself.

Comment: @Barmar: Ehm, no! Use a pointer to a 1D VLA! `int (*int_alloc2D(size_t rows, size_t cols))[cols];`. Use normal index-operator. Note the index-operator anyway does not operate on arrays, but pointers **only**.

Comment: If you have a better answer, post it.

Comment: I wait until it is clear what OP actually wants/needs. The question is not clear if that is a debug request or a "how to do" question. For example: Since when has an array  scalar "value"?